# MySQL - Date Difference and Flags

Tags: mysql, sql, date-difference

I am very new to `MySQL` and currently working on a table with three columns: `trx_id, user_id, last_activity`. (Churn Analysis)

**tbl_activity:**

[image: tbl_activity]

The table capture activity of users. I am finding it difficulty in performing two tasks.

1) I would like to see two new columns through SQL query

- date difference between subsequent transactions.
- flag based on condition > 30 days.

**Desired table:**

[image: desired table]

2) One of the objectives of this study is to identify when (date) a customer churned. Ideally in my case it would be the 31st day since last activity. Any way to arrive at this date?

I am new to SQL learning and finding it difficult to address SQL queries for the above tasks.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Search on "How to replicate Lead function in MySQL" and give it a try

Comment: @jarlh i have tried something like the below

Comment: SELECT distinct
    ch.id recharge_id,
 sub.user_id,
    DATE(sub.last_activity),
    date(ch.last_activity),
    IFNULL(DATEDIFF(DATE(ch.last_activity), (SELECT 
                    MAX(DATE(last_activity))
                FROM
                    tbl_activity l1
                WHERE
                    l1.user_id = ch.user_id
                    AND DATE(l1.last_activity) < DATE(ch.last_activity))), 0) days_diff
     
FROM
    tbl_users sub
        LEFT JOIN
    tbl_activity ch ON ch.user_id = sub.user_id
 order by user_id,ch.id;

Comment: Are you try my Answer. Is it helpful or not?

Comment: @DineshDB it was helpful. Is there any way for the second task which i have mentioned in my question? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

**For SQL Server:**

```
CREATE TABLE #tbl_activity(Trx_ID INT, User_Id INT, Last_Activity DATETIME)

INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(1,1100,'2015-06-08')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(2,1100,'2015-06-10')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(3,1100,'2015-06-10')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(4,1100,'2015-06-12')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(5,1100,'2015-06-13')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(6,1100,'2015-06-14')
INSERT INTO #tbl_activity VALUES(7,1100,'2015-09-25')

SELECT T1.Trx_ID, T1.User_Id, T1.Last_Activity
    ,DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.Last_Activity, T2.Last_Activity) days_Diff
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, T1.Last_Activity, T2.Last_Activity) >30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Flag
FROM #tbl_activity T1
LEFT JOIN #tbl_activity T2 ON T1.Trx_ID = T2.Trx_ID-1

DROP TABLE #tbl_activity
```

**For MySQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_activity(Trx_ID INT, User_Id INT, Last_Activity DATETIME)

INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(1,1100,'2015-06-08')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(2,1100,'2015-06-10')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(3,1100,'2015-06-10')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(4,1100,'2015-06-12')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(5,1100,'2015-06-13')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(6,1100,'2015-06-14')
INSERT INTO tbl_activity VALUES(7,1100,'2015-09-25')

SELECT T1.Trx_ID, T1.User_Id, T1.Last_Activity
    ,DATEDIFF(T2.Last_Activity, T1.Last_Activity) days_Diff
    ,CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(T2.Last_Activity, T1.Last_Activity) >30 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Flag
FROM tbl_activity T1
LEFT JOIN tbl_activity T2 ON T1.Trx_ID = T2.Trx_ID-1

DROP TABLE tbl_activity
```

Try this in [#SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0857f/2)

**Output:**

```
Trx_ID  User_Id Last_Activity           days_Diff   Flag
1       1100    2015-06-08 00:00:00.000     2       0
2       1100    2015-06-10 00:00:00.000     0       0
3       1100    2015-06-10 00:00:00.000     2       0
4       1100    2015-06-12 00:00:00.000     1       0
5       1100    2015-06-13 00:00:00.000     1       0
6       1100    2015-06-14 00:00:00.000     103     1
7       1100    2015-09-25 00:00:00.000     NULL    0
```